# CKEditor put focus on html type dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I'm trying to create a `select` dialog that supports `optgroup`.  The built in 'select' dialog doesn't handle that so I'm using the 'html' type dialog.  It's working fine, but I'd like to put the focus on that select box when the dialog opens.

I've tried various things, but I can't get it to work.  I'm wondering if I need to override `getInputElement()` and have it return the `select` element so I can call `focus()` on it, but I have no idea how to do that.

I also tried selecting the element with jQuery and using its `focus()` method, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can define a `focus()` function on the dialog element and in there make the appropriate call to the jQuery `.focus()`.

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'myDialog', function( editor ) {
    "use strict";

    return {
        title: 'Custom Dialog',

        contents: [
            {
                id: 'tab-basic',

                elements: [
                    {
                        type: 'html',
                        id: 'mealplan_select',
                        html: '<select id="my-select"></select>',
                        focus: function() {
                            $('#my-select').focus();
                        },
                        onShow: function() {
                            // focus this element
                            this.getInputElement().focus();
                        }  
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
});
```